# HTTP Status 500 - No adapter for handler [Controller Object]: The DispatcherServlet configuration needs to include a HandlerAdapter

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am entering a random string(request) then i am getting above mentioned error.

Ex: localhost:8080/ApplicationName/(any random string)

I have not configured this in request mapping url in my controller but i need to handle this exception from my application.

I have added @RequestMapping(value = { "**" }) in controller but due to this,
I am unable to access my css/js/image folder from WEB-INF/resources folder even i configured in our xml file.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: css/js/image resources folder should not be placed in  WEB-INF because WEB-INF resources are not directly visible for the public

Comment: Thanks @georgesvan for your quick response but I don't want my resources to be public. Only issue is, i want to handle any request that is not mapped in controller.